# How to start rx-android computation scheduler on demand?

Tags: android, rx-android

We are using RxAndroid in our app. The app do not use computation scheduler. Noticed several threads are started related to computation scheduler. The rxAndroid code by default set max threads to number of cores on the phone.

Is there a way to start computation scheduler on first use OR set max threads count?

I know there is a way to provide custom scheduler thru RxPlugin. Is there any other option to use default computation scheduler but with less number of threads or start it on demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my question, hopefully it will be helpful to someone. There is a system property "rx.scheduler.max-computation-threads" to limit the max number of computation threads. In my scenario I set it to 1 during app init.